# Struts html:form with different actions

Tags: html, forms, struts, submit, struts-action

I have a jsp with a submit based on the html:form action.

```
<html:form action="/nextPath">
```

I want to set the action based on a variable, or current path.. etc

```
<d:isActionPath path="/path1" >
    <html:form action="/nextPath1">
</d:isActionPath>

<d:isActionPath path="/path2" >
    <html:form action="/nextPath2">
</d:isActionPath>
```

This does not work. But this is essentially want I want to do.

Any suggestions? Very new to struts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<d:isActionPath path="/path1" >
    <c:set var="theAction" value="/nextPath1"/>
</d:isActionPath>

<d:isActionPath path="/path2" >
    <c:set var="theAction" value="/nextPath2"/>
</d:isActionPath>

<html:form action="${theAction}">
    ...
</html:form>
```

JSP tags must be balanced correctly, as in a XML document. You can't open a tag `d:isActionPath`, open a tag `html:form` and close the `d:isActionPath` tag without having closed the `html:form` tag.

Comment: Thanks! i actually did this using a scriplet and java, which is the same as this!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

> Cannot retrieve mapping for action /${theAction}

I replaced *${theAction}* by *<%= theAction %>* and it worked for me (struts 1.2.9, J2SE-1.5 and jboss-4.2.3.GA).

So you may try something like:

```
<% String theAction = "/nextPath"; %>
<d:isActionPath path="/path1" >
    <% theAction = "/nextPath1"; %>
</d:isActionPath>

<d:isActionPath path="/path2" >
    <% theAction = "/nextPath2"; %>
</d:isActionPath>

<html:form action="<%= theAction %>">
    ...
</html:form>
```

Edit: I’m confuse actually, why is it working with the ***<%= %>*** notation? Is it because the ***html*** tag is not interpreted correctly?